# Identify in which table view Cell button was pressed?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have table view cells like quiz. And in each cell I have a buttons And how can I identify in which cell button was pressed. Maybe by IndexPath??? 
This is how I connected button to

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "QuestionCell")!
     variant1 = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(1) as! UIButton
     variant2 = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(2) as! UIButton
     variant3 = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(3) as! UIButton
     variant4 = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(4) as! UIButton

    variant1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.variant1ButtonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
    variant2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.variant2ButtonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
    variant3.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.variant3ButtonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
    variant4.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.variant4ButtonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)

    return cell
}

func variant1ButtonPressed() {
    print("Variant1")
    variant1.backgroundColor = UIColor.green


}
func variant2ButtonPressed() {
    print("Variant2")
    variant2.backgroundColor = UIColor.green


}
func variant3ButtonPressed() {
    print("Variant3")
    variant3.backgroundColor = UIColor.green

}
func variant4ButtonPressed() {
    print("Variant4")
    variant4.backgroundColor = UIColor.green

}
```

This is how it looks like in Storyboard: [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this line to get indexPath, Where you have to pass `UIButton` on target selector

```
func buttonTapped(_ sender:AnyObject) {
    let buttonPosition:CGPoint = sender.convert(CGPointZero, to:self.tableView)
    let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRow(at: buttonPosition)
}
```

Comment: exchange CGPointZero to CGPoint.zero It has helped me ! Thanx

Comment: Thank you , It is very important to work with rect rather than setting tag as per indexpath , In case of row deletion or adding may cause problem in that case , so it is very safe idea to go with rect

Answer (score 9):

You should use delegate pattern, basic example:

```
protocol MyCellDelegate {
    func didTapButtonInside(cell: MyCell)
}

class MyCell: UITableViewCell {

    weak var delegate: MyCellDelegate?

    func buttonTapAction() {
        delegate?.didTapButtonInside(cell: self)
    }
}

class ViewController: MyCellDelegate {

    let tableView: UITableView

    func didTapButtonInside(cell: MyCell) {
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell) {
            print("User did tap cell with index: \(indexPath.row)")
        }
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since actions need to be inside the view controller, ctrl + drag from your button to the view controller - this will use the [responder chain](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/understanding_event_handling_responders_and_the_responder_chain).

Basically you need to convert the view (button) to the coordinate system of the table view in order to tell what is the IndexPath and if you have the IndexPath you have the object that corresponds to the button inside the cell that was tapped:

```
@IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        if let indexPath = indexPath(of: sender) {
            // Your implementation...
        }
    }

private func indexPath(of element:Any) -> IndexPath? {
        if let view =  element as? UIView {
            // Converting to table view coordinate system
            let pos = view.convert(CGPoint.zero, to: self.tableView)
            // Getting the index path according to the converted position
            return tableView.indexPathForRow(at: pos) as? IndexPath
        }
        return nil
    }
```

It is important to mention that there many solutions for your question. But you should know that in Apple's sample projects they also use this technic.

Comment: I'd recommend against force casting in any code base. Don't use ! when you can avoid it, be wary of crashes.

Comment: It looks like you're still force casting. Why cast at all? just return `tableView.indexPathForRow(at: pos)`

Comment: @cloudcal, Of course I am force casting, I'v validated that the return object isn't nil. But you are correct again since I am already returning optional type. Code updated :)

Comment: Right. But according to OP, buttons are attached inside the UITableViewCells. It's better to send a delegate call with the `UITableViewCell`, i.e., `func tableViewCellDidTapButton(_ cell: UITableViewCell)` back to the controller, and then call `tableView.indexPath(for: UITableViewCell)` if you need to know which row, or just operate on the cell itself since a pointer to it is sent back with the delegate.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you add tag to a UIButton inside UITableView, add below lines of code in

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell

cell.yourButton.tag = indexPath.row
cell.yourButton.addTarget(self, action:#selector(btnPressed(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Add this function in your ViewController

```
func btnPressed(sender: UIButton)
{
   print("Button tag \(sender.tag)")
}
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Simple Subclass button just like **JSIndexButton**

```
class JSIndexButton : UIButton {

     var indexPath : IndexPath!

}
```

Now at **cellForRowAt**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ItemCell

    let itemCategory = dataList[button.indexPath.section];
    let item = itemCategory.items[button.indexPath.row];

    cell.imgView.setImageWithURL(item.photoUrl);
    cell.btnBuy.indexPath = indexPath;
    cell.btnBuy.addTarget(self, action: #selector(JSCollapsableTableView.btnBuyPressed(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

    return cell;

}
```

Check Button **Action**

```
@IBAction func btnBuyPressed(_ button: JSIndexButton) {

    let itemCategory = dataList[button.indexPath.section];
    let item = itemCategory.items[button.indexPath.row];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 @objc func ItemsDescription(_ sender: UIButton?,event: AnyObject?) {
    let touches: Set<UITouch>
    touches = (event?.allTouches!)!
    let touch:UITouch = (touches.first)!
    let touchPosition:CGPoint = touch.location(in: self.tableView)
    let indexPath:NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRow(at: touchPosition)! as NSIndexPath
}
```

> adding target

```
cell.ItemsDescription.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ItemsDescription(_:event:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
```